# How to read from /write to anonymous shared mapping?

Tags: c, fork, semaphore, mmap

Attempting to write a message to anonymous shared memory with a child process, terminate it. Then have the message read by the parent. I have seen examples for mapping input & output files using file descriptors obtained through `read` & `write` calls. But do not know how to approach this correctly.

```
int main(void) {
  char *shared; 
  int status;
  pid_t child;

  shared = mmap(0, sizeof(int) , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);

  if (shared == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    return 1;
  }

  child = fork();

  if ( child == -1 ) {
    perror("fork");
    return 1;
  } else if (child == 0) {
    sprintf(shared, "foo");

  } else {
    printf("%s", shared);
    wait(&status);
  }

  if (munmap (shared, sizeof(int)) == -1) {
      perror("munmap");
      return 1;
  }

  return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Almost there, you need two things: a method to synchronize the parent so it does'nt read before the child writes and the actual read and write which can be done normally with `write` and `read` calls. read the manual for semaphores: http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview. try solving it yourself, you are inches away (:

Comment: @IshayPeled I know that I can use 1 as `read`'s first argument to display the message to the screen. I thought that, in this case, `write` requires a file desc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only goal is to read / write between a child process and a parent process, using pipes is a much easier method of doing so. It would look something like this:

```
    int fd[2]; 
    pipe(fd);

    if((child= fork()) == -1)
    {
            perror("fork");
            exit(1);
    }

    if(child == 0)
    {
            // close read side
            close(fd[0]);

            // write to pipe
            write(fd[1], msg, (strlen(msg));
    }
    else
    {
            //close write side
            close(fd[1]);

            //read what the child wrote. 
            nbytes = read(fd[0], buff, sizeof(buff));
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to bother with shared memory, then it's silly to try to manipulate it by `read()` and `write()` calls on the underlying file (which for an anonymous mapping doesn't exist anyway).  If you want to communicate via `read()` and `write()` then just create a pipe instead, and forget about mapping and shared memory.  That is in fact an entirely viable approach.

If you really do want to use shared memory for this, then use it like *memory*.  Convert the pointer to the shared memory region to an appropriate pointer-to-object type, use ordinary assignment to write, and use ordinary variable / memory access to read.  Shared memory does introduce potential issues with conflicting access and synchronization, but even that's no big deal for the simple case you describe: just have the parent process successfully `wait()` for the child (or otherwise be notified of its termination) before it attempts to read whatever the child wrote.

You do have an issue with how you are setting up your mapping, however: you map `sizeof(int)` bytes, but this is probably not enough for the message you attempt to write.  Overall, it should look more like this:

```
int main(void) {
  char *message;
  int status;
  pid_t child;

  message = mmap(NULL, BUFSIZE , PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED | MAP_ANON, -1, 0);

  if (message == MAP_FAILED) {
    perror("mmap");
    return 1;
  }

  child = fork();

  if ( child == -1 ) {
    perror("fork");
    return 1;
  } else if (child == 0) {
    strcpy( message, "foo\n");
  } else {
    wait(&status);
    printf("The child wrote:\n%s\n", message);
  }

  return 0;    
}
```